# python padding decimals with zeros

Tags: python, format

I'm looking for a way to pad the float decimals with zeros:

This one is my reference:

```
In [37]: '{:5.5}'.format(round(4.123456, 5))
Out[37]: '4.1235'
```

I have this:

```
In [38]: '{:5.5}'.format(4.1)
Out[38]: '  4.1'
```

But I would like to have this:

```
Out[38]: '4.1000'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) a floating point number with a given precision you should use the `'f'` specifier. Without it the value is formatted as a string.

```
>>> '{:.4f}'.format(4.1)
'4.1000
```

You can also specify the *minimum width* of the complete output and the fill character:

```
>>> '{:07.4f}'.format(4.1)
'04.1000'
```

Here the output is padded on the left with zeros to be at least 7 characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
 '{:5.5f}'.format(4.1)
```

The f in the format string makes the difference here. You can read more about the formatters in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), important for this task is

> 'f'   Fixed point. Displays the number as a fixed-point number. The
>   default precision is 6.

But you wanted just 4 digits after the comma, so better is

```
>>> '{:.4f}'.format(4.1)
'4.1000'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'{:5.5f}'.format(4.1)
```

[pyformat.info](http://www.pyformat.info)