# how to deal with python float number with certain precision

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
a = 1.00
print(a)
>>> 1.0
```

Is there a way to transfer this a variable here into a string value
str_a = "1.00" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python padding decimals with zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186526/python-padding-decimals-with-zeros)

Answer (score 4):

You can use format strings:

```
str_a = '{0:.2f}'.format(a)
print(str_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use fstrings with ':.xf' where x specifies number of decimal places.

```
a = 1.2345
str_a = f'{a:.2f}'
print(str_a)

Out: 1.23
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out the Decimal library. should have what you looking for and can also have decimals with extreme precision

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html